# How do I redirect missing *.htm pages to a known page in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

We've recently replaced an old HTML site with a shiny new Ruby on Rails one. Unfortunately a lot of the search engines are still looking for pages like 'index.htm' which no longer exist.

We already have a default route which catches bad URLs and gives a 404, but for URLs which end in .htm, I'd prefer to redirect to different page instead with a 302.

This is what we currently use a catch-all:

```
match '*a', :to => 'errors#routing'
```

What can I add above that to catch 'index.htm' and anything else *.htm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `match '*a.htm' => redirect("/", :status => 302)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Rails routes that are identical to the legacy routes (without `.html` at the end), you should be able to add an optional `:format` in your routes.  Check out the defalt catch all route definition:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

The key is `(.:format)` at the end. Try adding that to other routes and it should work with legacy and non-legacy URLs.

Comment: The OP asked for matching *.htm, so you'd need to add a constraint like `:constraints => {:format => /\Ahtm\Z/}`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the first solution without much success. This worked fine though.

```
match '*a.htm', to: 'errors#redirect_to_home'
```

where the errors controller is:

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def routing
    render_404
  end

  def redirect_to_home
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe try `match '*a.htm' => redirect("/")` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

Comment: Does that still give a 302 status?

Comment: Whoops, forgot about the 302. By default the redirect is returned with 301 status, but you can override that: `match '*a.htm' => redirect("/", :status => 302)`

Comment: Hey Wizard. If you write that up as your answer, I'll tick if off.